# how to post string data in byte format to server?

Tags: android

I want to send a string data, "" , in bytes format to server in android app. I uses the HttpClient but i think its not the right way, please help me how to do this?

in case of .net , i want similar code in java.

```
    string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
        as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "POST";
    //request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    byte[] fulldata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    request.ContentLength = fulldata.Length;
    using (Stream sw = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        sw.Write(fulldata, 0, fulldata.Length);
    }
```

Comment: "I think its not the right way" - You could try: IP over Avian Carriers (IPoAC) if you feel that a HttpClient is not suitable, it has high latency but can delivery a lot of data in a single packet [see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers]

Comment: using HttpClient you can send the byte data to server. See my answer hope it ll help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First convert your string data to byte and by using ByteArrayEntity send data to server in byte format.**

try like this

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/xxx");
HttpResponse response;
HttpParams hp = new BasicHttpParams();

//use ByteArrayEntity to send string data in byteformat
ByteArrayEntity byteEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(byte_data);
httppost.setEntity(byteEntity);
response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: I am getting an error , java.net.UnknownHostException: xxxx.sitename.com, in line ,   HttpResponse responseHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: have you used permission in manifest like this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: goto this link.. http://guerrarj.hubpages.com/hub/Tips-to-solve-the-UnknownHostException-on-Android .. might you have problem with one of them solutions..

Comment: @IndraKP, In server side also , you have to use ByteArrayEntity format to receive the request from client... otherwise check your link....

Comment: on the server side they are using,  HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())), now i am getting null value
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
            ss = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }